# how to fix undefined value error in code below

Tags: jquery, html

I am retrieving a `referenceError stating: value is not defined`. Im trying to set a `Remove` button as a value so that it removes the text input associated with the value. But I do not know what to set the `value` to in order to fix the error because `var value=''` did not work. What do I suppose to set `value` to?

Below is code:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imageID, imagefilename){

      var result = '';
      imagecounter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';   
            $('.hiddenimg').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<input type="text" name="imgid[]" id="'+imageID+'" value="' + imageID + '" />');
            $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" data-imageID="'+imageID+'"  data-image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '" value="'+imageID+'">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>');
         }


  var _imagecounter = imagecounter;

$('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {
    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + $(this).attr('data-image_file_name')).done(function(data) {
        $(".imagemsg" + _imagecounter).html(data);
    });

    var buttonid = $(this).attr(value);
    $(this).parent().remove();
     $("#"+ buttonid  +"").remove();
});

      return true;   
}
```

Comment: Which live gives you the error?

Comment: Are you looking for `$(this).val()`? Or, since `buttonid` suggests you are looking for the id, do you want `$(this).attr("id")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var buttonid = $(this).attr(value);
```

to

```
var buttonid = $(this).attr('value');
```

or initialize value to some attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need

```
var buttonid = $(this).attr('value');
```

Or `value` is an undefined variable